# Angular development setup without using CLI

Tags: angular

I started to learn and do some demo apps with Angular but I'm still struggling to have a clear big picture about how everything is working and what is the concept and the idea behind. Almost all resources I have found include CLI and everything seems to be so automated, preconfigured and easy but I don't like that, at least while I'm learning.

Does anyone know some resources where you can learn Angular and development setup around it, but without using CLI and all this magic behind? So, pure, old school step by step, file by file guide which gives you deeper understanding.

I believe there has to be a way to have basic setup with some minimal number of packages and dependencies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's articles online about how to do this, such as this one: 
https://blog.angularindepth.com/setting-up-angular-from-scratch-1f518c65d8ab

If you want to get your head around how the Angular CLI project fits together, then I suggest you begin by learning WebPack. https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

Once you understand the basics of WebPack; the Angular CLI and the file structure it generates will make a lot more sense. You will understand how the project fits together and how you can modify it to suit your needs ... at least it did for me.